# Binance API take profit and stop loss with limit orders

Tags: python, binance

I have been trying to place the orders on Binance using API in Python.

What works is below. Below is my initial order for buy when the price hits.

```
response = client.new_order(
    symbol="BONDUSDT",
    side="BUY",
    positionSide="LONG",
    type="LIMIT",
    quantity=quantity,
    timeInForce="GTC",
    price=4.493,
)
```

However when I try to put a stoploss or take profit order. I get errors:

```
take_profit_position = client.new_order(
        symbol=symbol,
        side='SELL',
        closePosition = True,
        type="TAKE_PROFIT",
        positionSide="LONG",
        price=4.754,
        stopPrice=4.754,
        timeInForce="GTE_GTC"
    )
```

Error is
`400, -4136, 'Target strategy invalid for orderType STOP,closePosition true',`

Same error for Stop Loss:

```
stop_loss_position = client.new_order(
        symbol=symbol,
        side='SELL',
        closePosition = True,
        type="STOP",
        positionSide="LONG",
        stopPrice=4.012,
        timeInForce="GTE_GTC"
    )
```

I also tried changing GTE_GTC to GTC. It did not work.

I also tried TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET and same error came.

Comment: I have also tried  existing solutions on stack, they don't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what types of orders are available for this specific pair first.  There doesn't seem to be `TAKE_PROFIT` nor `TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET` for this one.

```
curl -s https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo?symbol=$pair | jq .
```

for the pair you've mentioned it gives

```
      "orderTypes": [
        "LIMIT",
        "LIMIT_MAKER",
        "MARKET",
        "STOP_LOSS_LIMIT",
        "TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT"
      ],
```